# How to add water mark to image using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
    string fname = "";
    string filename = ""; 
    if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0)
    {           
        HttpFileCollection files = context.Request.Files; 
        for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
        {
            HttpPostedFile file = files[i];
            string filess = files[i].FileName;


            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "IE" || HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "INTERNETEXPLORER")
            {
                string[] testfiles = file.FileName.Split(new char[] { '\\' });
                fname = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMMyyyyhhmissmmm") + testfiles[testfiles.Length - 1];
                filename = filename + Path.GetFileName(fname);
            }
            else   
            {//some code here 
                fname = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMMyyyyhhmissmmm") + file.FileName;
                filename = filename + Path.GetFileName(fname);
            } 
            string replacestr = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(filename, "[^a-zA-Z0-9_]+", " ");
            fname = replacestr;
            fname = replacestr;
            fname = fname.Replace(" ", "").Replace(",", "").Trim();
            fname = fname + "";
            fname = fname + ".png"; 
            filename = fname;
```

fname = Path.Combine(context.Server.MapPath("../admin/img/product_images/"), fname);
                file.SaveAs(fname);

//some code here
            }
        }

Comment: What is your actual problem?

Comment: What does your code do now? What do you want it to do?

Comment: i want to add watermark on image after that save in particular folder. above code not working properly its save without watermark.

Comment: //i well done this code    byte[] bytes = wc.DownloadData(fname);
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
                System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms); Graphics graphicsobj = Graphics.FromImage(image);
                Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(80, 255, 255, 255)); Point postionWaterMark = new Point((image.Width / 2), (image.Height * 9 / 10));    graphicsobj.DrawString("© Articlemirror.in", new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 30, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel), brush, postionWaterMark);

Comment: string filepath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("../admin/img/product_images/") + filename;

Answer (score 2):

//Do This Work watermark[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veD4i.png)

```
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(file.InputStream);
            Graphics graphicsobj = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
            Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(80, 255, 255, 255));
            Point postionWaterMark = new Point((enter image description herebmp.Width / 6), (bmp.Height / 2));
            graphicsobj.DrawString("Daphnisys Technology", new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 30, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel), brush, postionWaterMark);
            Image img = (Image)bmp;
            string filepath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("../admin/img/product_images/") + filename;
            //image.Save(filepath);
            img.Save(filepath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            graphicsobj.Dispose();
```